# Saving My Large Basil Plant - Help?

Tags: leaves, herbs, sunlight, basil, fleshy-leaves

I have a seven-year-old basil plant which is about 5 feet tall. I accidentally burned all the leaves spraying with the wrong spray bottle. Although the tree was doing well after all the leaves dropped, it looks like all the stems are starting to dry fast. Any suggestions on how I can save it?

Comment: What was in the spray bottle that you used on your basil?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.